# How to map all the code referenced from the Fitnesse tests?

Tags: c#, fitnesse

**Rationale:** We want to refactor our Fitnesse code (we use .NET and fitSharp). However, some methods are called from the Fitnesse through reflection and these methods make it very hard to do refactoring safely.

Is there a way to map all the code invoked from Fitnesse? Ideally, we would have some kind of an object model we can inspect or a visitor we can use and get called back for every property or method mentioned in the content.txt files.

Is it possible?